# How do I use an aggregate function and select a specific column using Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by, aggregate-functions

How would I use Rails ActiveRecord to write a query similar to this?

```
select
    table1.category as "Collection",
    count(table4.category) as "Totals"
from
    table1 
group by table1.name
order by "Totals" desc
```

The goal here is to simply report on the number of categories in the table. I've tried a few permutations of `.select()` and `.count()`, but my newbness is too great. =/

Maybe it will help if I provide an expected results set. Something like:

```
| Collection | Totals |
| ---------- | ------ |
| category1  |     10 |
| category5  |      9 |
| category8  |      5 |
| category3  |      3 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Collection.pluck(:category).inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }
```

Comment: Interesting. So, it seems there is no AR equiv, eh? Just so I understand, you're taking all the records from the query and putting them in a new Hash, while iterating over each record, and adding to the Hash value?

Comment: You're exactly right. The query just returns an array of all of the categories, so at least you're not making a pile of Collections. I can't think of a way to do it in AR better (or at all, off the too of my head)...